# Windows app certification kit 2.2 fails to find any apps to validate

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit, wack

I'm running windows 8 and visual studio express for windows 8.

I have created an app and had it successfully submitted to the app store.

I am now working on a second app and getting ready to submit it.  However, I just updated to the latest win8 SDK and to Windows app certification kit 2.2.  Ever since I updated, I have been unable to run the cert kit.

Whenever I run the cert kit as part of the 'create app packages' I get the following error.  I find it interesting that my first app gets the same behavior.

The {0} cannot continue testing since the specified Windows Store App was not found.  Please verify the packagefullname is correct.

So, I try running the Windows App Certification kit 2.2 in stand-alone mode.  When I select to certify windows store app, it thinks for a bit and then returns with an empty list of applications.

I found the following link wack doesn't see my app and followed the steps but still no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm that you are using the RTM build of Windows 8? This was a bug discovered in pre-RTM builds that should have been fixed for RTM.

Comment: winver.exe says that it is version 6.2(build9200)

Comment: I am with the same problem. Win8 RTM, app is listed by Get-AppxPackage but appcert fails.